# Calling a method as an int value in an array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, class, methods

I'm trying to create a class and set up some variables in the **init** portion that will call certain indexes in the array when the class is called.
Howeever, my index method does not seem to be working correctly in this context as I get this error

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [82], in <cell line: 17>()
     14     def index(self, n = 0):
     15         return (len(self.array) - n).astype(int)
---> 17 something = Do_something()

Input In [82], in Do_something.__init__(self, a_number)
      6 self.number = a_number
      7 self.array = np.zeros((1,3), dtype = float)  
----> 9 self.a = self.array[self.index,0]
     10 self.b = self.array[self.index,1]
     11 self.c = self.array[self.index,2]

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

Here is the script

```
import numpy as np

class Do_something:
   
    def __init__(self, a_number = 0):
        self.number = a_number
        self.array = np.zeros((1,3), dtype = float)  
        
        self.a = self.array[self.index,0]
        self.b = self.array[self.index,1]
        self.c = self.array[self.index,2]
    
     #return a negative indwex of n
    def index(self, n = 0):
        return (len(self.array) - n).astype(int)
    
something = Do_something()
```

What am I not doing correcly?

EDIT
Fixed it by adding the parenthesesto the self.index and adding n + 1 to the return of the index function.

```
import numpy as np

class Do_something:
   
    def __init__(self, a_number = 0):
        self.number = a_number
        self.array = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6], [7,8,9]])  
        
        self.a = self.array[self.index(),0]
        self.b = self.array[self.index(),1]
        self.c = self.array[self.index(),2]
    
     #return a negative indwex of n
    def index(self, n = 2):

        return (len(self.array) - (n + 1))

    
something = Do_something()
print("length is " + str(len(something.array)))
# print(len(something.array) - (0-1))
print(something.a)
print(something.b)
print(something.index())
```

Thanks :)

Comment: `self.index` is a method. Did you mean to use `self.index(1)`?

Comment: Whoops good call I forgot the parenthesis.
However what I am trying to do is have the index function call the array in reverse, so zero = the last row and 1 = the second to last row value etc. Maybe I'm stupid but I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around how to make that work without index errors.

Comment: Python indexing accepts '-1' as last, '-2' as second to the last etc